# Error: column is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type double precision

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

The following code...

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
import datetime
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import re
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event
import pandas as pd
import runpy
import codecs
import collections
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
import threading
import os
import csv
import warnings
import xlsxwriter
from threading import Timer
import psycopg2

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import time
import win32com.client
import threading
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import runpy
import codecs
import collections
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import threading
from datetime import timedelta
import warnings
from win32com import client
from datetime import datetime
import os
#from docx import Document
#from docx.shared import Inches, Pt, Mm
import time
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import runpy
import codecs
import collections
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import threading
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
import os
import time
import glob
import time
import time
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
import time
import win32com.client
import threading
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import runpy
import codecs
import collections
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import threading
from datetime import timedelta
import warnings
from win32com import client
from datetime import datetime
import os
#from docx import Document
#from docx.shared import Inches, Pt, Mm
import time
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import runpy
import codecs
import collections
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import threading
from datetime import timedelta
import warnings
from win32com import client
from datetime import datetime
import os
import time
import glob
import time
import time
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
kronos_df = pd.read_excel(r"\\teslamotors.com\us\Public\stalamakki\ExcelFiles\KronosDataHourlyRefresh.xls")

kronos_df.fillna('')
clockRecords = kronos_df.to_dict('records')

sqlUpsert = """
                        INSERT INTO "daily_performance_metrics"."employee_kronos_data_2"
                        VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
"""
#                        VALUES (%s,to_timestamp(%s, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),COALESCE(to_timestamp(NULLIF(%s, '01/01/01 00:00'),'MM/DD/YY hh24:mi')),%s,%s)

#sqlDelete = """
#        DELETE FROM "daily_performance_metrics"."employee_kronos_data" WHERE CustomerName='Alfreds Futterkiste';

postgres_conn = psycopg2.connect("host=sjc04p1scadb02.teslamotors.com dbname=service_warehouse_metrics user=service_warehouse_rw port=5432 password=gvjY96LcnWn2B3+obVjFsLG5erMy/4JNxgN00Lnq2n0=")
postgres_cursor = postgres_conn.cursor()
for record in clockRecords:
    if record['ShiftEnd'] == '':
       record['ShiftEnd'] = None
    if record['ShiftStart'] == '':
       record['ShiftStart'] = None
    postgres_cursor.execute(sqlUpsert,list(record.values()))
postgres_conn.commit()
postgres_cursor.close()
postgres_conn.close()
```

...generates this error message when it tries to write what I assume is the first record with a null value...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DatatypeMismatch                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-2ef7c8c3820c> in <module>()
     15     if record['ShiftStart'] == 'NaN':
     16        record['ShiftStart'] = None
---> 17 postgres_cursor.execute(sqlUpsert,list(record.values()))
     18 postgres_conn.commit()
     19 postgres_cursor.close()

DatatypeMismatch: column "shift_end" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type double precision
LINE 3: ...              VALUES ('zvolkert','10/02/19 13:13','NaN'::flo...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

To deal with the Nulls, I've tried this syntax for the INSERT statement...

```
INSERT INTO "daily_performance_metrics"."employee_kronos_data_2"
VALUES (%s,to_timestamp(%s, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),COALESCE(to_timestamp(NULLIF(%s, '01/01/01 00:00'),'MM/DD/YY hh24:mi')),%s,%s)
```

...which generates this error message...

```
InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "01/01/01 00:00"
LINE 3: ...4:MI'),COALESCE(to_timestamp(NULLIF('NaN'::float, '01/01/01 ...
```

I'm assuming this is a very simple syntax mistake. Would really appreciate if someone could tell me the correct syntax for getting these strings and null values into the timestamp fields.

I'm writing to this table...

```
CREATE TABLE daily_performance_metrics.employee_kronos_data_5 (
    file_number TEXT
    ,shift_start TIMESTAMP
    ,shift_end TIMESTAMP
    ,job_category TEXT
    ,job_name TEXT
    )
```

Here's the file that i'm trying to copy to the database:

[ClockInOutRecords.xlsx](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=0A882D15600C2281&resid=A882D15600C2281%21329&authkey=ABG_DRZjBwgQXao)

Comment: I don't think [NULLIF()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) in PostgreSQL works like you think it does.

Comment: I feel like your values are not in the expected order... Can you give us the value of ```list(record.values())``` right before the error comes up? And why does your errormessage quote codelines that do not exist in your code (do you have a copy error here)?

Comment: @Islingre, I just checked and all the lines in my code are posted above. what line in the error message isn't in the code?

Comment: @Islingre Here;s what's in list(record.values())
['zvolkert', '10/02/19 13:13', nan, nan, nan]

Comment: I messed up the indentation for this line in the original post...
postgres_cursor.execute(sqlUpsert,list(record.values()))
The post has been edited with the correct indentation.

Comment: So you are having 3 NaN values and you try to insert them into columns of what datatype? I guess there is your problem, since the 3rd column seems to be of type ```timestamp``` and not ```float```. Perhaps you also want to insert ```null``` and not ```NaN``` if you have no value?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simply to replace the nan values with none. I thought I was already doing that but the == 'NaN' syntax was incorrect. The correct syntax for checking for NaN is pd.isna. Fixed code below...

```
sqlUpsert = """
                        INSERT INTO "daily_performance_metrics"."employee_kronos_data_2"                        
                        VALUES (%s,COALESCE(to_timestamp(%s, 'MM/DD/YY hh24:mi')),COALESCE(to_timestamp(%s, 'MM/DD/YY hh24:mi')),%s,%s)
"""
#                        VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
#                        VALUES (%s,to_timestamp(%s, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),COALESCE(to_timestamp(NULLIF(%s, '01/01/01 00:00'),'MM/DD/YY hh24:mi')),%s,%s)

postgres_conn = psycopg2.connect("host=sjc04p1scadb02.teslamotors.com dbname=service_warehouse_metrics user=service_warehouse_rw port=5432 password=gvjY96LcnWn2B3+obVjFsLG5erMy/4JNxgN00Lnq2n0=")
postgres_cursor = postgres_conn.cursor()

postgres_cursor.execute(sqlDelete)

for record in clockRecords:
#    print(list(record.values()))
    if pd.isna(record['ShiftEnd']):
#        print(record['ShiftEnd'])
        record['ShiftEnd'] = None
#        print(record['ShiftEnd'])
    if pd.isna(record['Job_Category']):
        record['Job_Category'] = None
    if pd.isna(record['Job_Name']):
        record['Job_Name'] = None
#    print(list(record.values()))
    postgres_cursor.execute(sqlUpsert,list(record.values()))
#    print('success')
```